# Is there a way to keep my google map V2 instead of V3 compliant?

Tags: google-maps

I just discovered that the google map on my site is no longer working correctly because all the functions which refer to the deprecated V2 don't work. My source for the google maps api javascript is

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=....."
```

which, because it says v=2, I assumed would reference V2. Apparently it doesn't, because the V2 functions are throwing errors. Is there any way to keep my javascript working without updating it all to be V3 compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a version number if you need to stay on that version (i.e. v=2.242) per the documentation.  Their "official changelog" (mentioned at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/basics.html#API_Updates) doesn't appear to be up-to-date, so I'm not sure of the best way to get the version number that you want, other than trial and error.

Comment: It's not working so far. I'm not sure if it's because I haven't entered in a correct version number (I tried 2.75 and 2.5) or for some other reason...